# Spinner duplication item error

Tags: android, spinner

How to remove duplicate data in spinner because when I select spinner again it will show duplication of data. Any solutions, please?

Like when click on bike. it shows detail of all bike on other spinner.
then I select again from that spinner like bike or other item. It shows again bike detail. Information duplicate on other spinners which contains bike information.

For example when I click on bike it shows Honda yamaha suzuki other then I again click on Bike spinner it wil shows Honda yamaha suzuki other Honda yamaha suzuki other.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    // Spinner Drop down elements
    vehicle_type.add("Select vehicle Type");
    vehicle_type.add("Bike");
    vehicle_type.add("Car");
    vehicle_type.add("Cycle");
    select_model.add("Select a Model");
    select_make.add("Select a Make");
    year.add("Select a Year");
```

// Creating adapter for spinner

```
    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button


    ArrayAdapter<String> vehicle_type_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, vehicle_type);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    vehicle_type_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(vehicle_type_adapter);

    ArrayAdapter<String> select_make_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, select_make);

    select_make_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner1.setAdapter(select_make_adapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> model_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, select_model);

    model_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner4.setAdapter(model_adapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> year_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, year);

    year_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner3.setAdapter(year_adapter);


}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
   // String item1=spinner1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    if(item=="Bike")
    {



        select_make.add("Honda");
        select_make.add("suzuki");
        select_make.add("sohrab");
        select_make.add("Yamaha");
        select_make.add("Other");
        select_model.add("100cc");
        select_model.add("125cc");
        select_model.add("70cc");
        select_model.add("150cc");
        select_model.add("Other");
        int i = 2000;
        int j = 1;
        String vt;
        String yearr;
        year.add("Year");
        for (i = 2000; i <= 2017; i++) {
            yearr = String.valueOf(i);
            year.add(yearr);

        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> year_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, year);

        year_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner3.setAdapter(year_adapter);
        ArrayAdapter<String> select_make_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, select_make);

       select_make_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner1.setAdapter(select_make_adapter);
        ArrayAdapter<String> model_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, select_model);

        model_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner4.setAdapter(model_adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just edit you code like this,....

```
if(item=="Bike")
{  //clear other spinner array list
   select_make.clear();
   select_model.clear();
   year.clear();

    select_make.add("Honda");
    select_make.add("suzuki");
    select_make.add("sohrab");
    select_make.add("Yamaha");
    select_make.add("Other");
    select_model.add("100cc");
    select_model.add("125cc");
    select_model.add("70cc");
    select_model.add("150cc");
    select_model.add("Other");
    int i = 2000;
    int j = 1;
    String vt;
    String yearr;
    year.add("Year");
    for (i = 2000; i <= 2017; i++) {
        yearr = String.valueOf(i);
        year.add(yearr);

    }
```

and after that why are you assigning adapter again?.. you don't need to do it... just stop coding further... setting adapter one time will enough

Comment: @WaleedAsim Your welcome bro, rather than saying thanks to anyone try to express your feeling by upvote, downvote or by approving the answer. I not telling you because i want upvote but because it is an good habit to appriciate someone. Thanks.

Comment: verify this answer if it works @WaleedAsim  its gonna help someone else..